# What exactly is working for the EventReservation type

Tags: google-schemas

I created a quite complex schema of the EventRegistration type.
It contained two tickets, had images, contact details, etc.
But all I could get once was a Now card that only contained the title of the event, the date, the location and a action button to open the mail.

I'm wondering, if all the additional data has some error or if this is currently all that is supported. I would have loved to see Logos, contact details, a cancellation link and of course the ticket itself (=QR-Code + download link). This would have been such a nice alternative to Apple's Passbook.

What are the plans for this feature? Is this still going to be developed, is there perhaps already a rough roadmap on when to expect this?

Additionally what I was wondering about is, that the "Email Markup Tester" was complaining that the ticketToken property would be invalid for that type, even though the documentation clearly states that it is part of the EventReservation type.

FYI, here is the anonymized schema I used:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context":              "http://schema.org",
  "@type":                 "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber":     "TFXLLUS00008",
  "reservationStatus":     "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type":               "Person",
    "name":                "Name 1",
    "email":               "...@gmail.com"
  },
  "bookingAgent": {
    "@type":               "Organization",
    "name":                "My company",
    "description":         "My company - online ticketing",
    "image":               "http://www.MyCompany.com/link/to/logo_1500x1500px.jpg",
    "url":                 "http://www.MyCompany.com",
    "url/googlePlus":      "https://plus.google.com/+MyCompany/",
    "ContactPoint": {
      "@type":             "ContactPoint",
      "email":             "support@MyCompany.com",
      "telephone":         "123456789"
    }
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type":               "Event",
    "name":                "Test-Event",
    "startDate":           "2014-04-26T20:00:00+00:00",
    "endDate":             "2014-04-30T18:00:00+00:00",
    "description":         "This is a test event for demo purposes.", 
    "image":               "http://www.MyCompany.com/link/to/event/logo.png", 
    "url":                 "http://www.MyCompany.com/link/to/event.html",  
    "location": {
      "@type":             "Place",
      "name":              "Congress hall",
      "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "Street. 1",
        "addressLocality": "City",
        "addressRegion":   "",
        "postalCode":      "12345",
        "addressCountry":  "DE"
      }
    }
  },
  "ticketToken":           "qrCode:4641484423168988",
  "ticketNumber":          "1690-8587-4723",
  "numSeats":              "1",
  "ticketDownloadUrl":     "https://www.MyCompany.com/linkToTicket.pdf",
  "ticketPrintUrl":        "https://www.MyCompany.com/linkToTicket.pdf",
  "price":                 "100",
  "priceCurrency":         "EUR",
  "bookingTime":           "2014-04-26T13:57:50+00:00",
  "modifiedTime":          "2014-04-26T13:57:50+00:00"
},
{
  "@context":              "http://schema.org",
  "@type":                 "EventReservation",
  "reservationNumber":     "TFXLLUS00008",
  "reservationStatus":     "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type":               "Person",
    "name":                "Name 2",
    "email":               "...@gmail.com"
  },
  "bookingAgent": {
    "@type":               "Organization",
    "name":                "My company",
    "description":         "My company - online ticketing",
    "image":               "http://www.MyCompany.com/link/to/logo_1500x1500px.jpg",
    "url":                 "http://www.MyCompany.com",
    "url/googlePlus":      "https://plus.google.com/+MyCompany/",
    "ContactPoint": {
      "@type":             "ContactPoint",
      "email":             "support@MyCompany.com",
      "telephone":         "123456789"
    }
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type":               "Event",
    "name":                "Test-Event",
    "startDate":           "2014-04-26T20:00:00+00:00",
    "endDate":             "2014-04-30T18:00:00+00:00",
    "description":         "This is a test event for demo purposes.", 
    "image":               "http://www.MyCompany.com/link/to/event/logo.png", 
    "url":                 "http://www.MyCompany.com/link/to/event.html",  
    "location": {
      "@type":             "Place",
      "name":              "Congress hall",
      "address": {
        "@type":           "PostalAddress",
        "streetAddress":   "Street. 1",
        "addressLocality": "City",
        "addressRegion":   "",
        "postalCode":      "12345",
        "addressCountry":  "DE"
      }
    }
  },
  "ticketToken":           "qrCode:4020229019819219",
  "ticketNumber":          "5218-3082-0382",
  "numSeats":              "1",
  "ticketDownloadUrl":     "https://www.MyCompany.com/linkToTicket.pdf",
  "ticketPrintUrl":        "https://www.MyCompany.com/linkToTicket.pdf",
  "price":                 "100",
  "priceCurrency":         "EUR",
  "bookingTime":           "2014-04-26T13:57:50+00:00",
  "modifiedTime":          "2014-04-26T13:57:50+00:00"
}
</script>
```

Comment: Gmail isn't following what schema.org says (on the examples page they still mention "action.url" instead of "potentialAction.target", so I'm not surprised you found a discrepancy.  Anyway, I'm facing the same problem now with EventReservation.  Even copy-pasting their example into the Apps Script tester doesn't result in a document that's recognized in Gmail.